# how to best define aggregation relation?

Tags: c#, relationship, aggregation, class-diagram

Sorry I couldn't find a better format for the question.

I have two classes (Design, Color )

The design class can have many colors, and for each color, the design can specify some attributes such as a name for the combination of (Design-Color) .

and then I have a Fabric class, which has a Design-Color combination.

what is the appropriate way to implement such a relationship between those classes ?

here is a suggested model (which I think is wrong):

```
class Design {
   public string Name { get;set;}

   public int StringNumber {get;set;}

///some other properties.
}

class Color {
   public string Name { get;set;}

///some other properties.
}

class ColoredDesign {
public Color Color { get;set;}

public Design Design { get;set;}

public string ColoredDesignName { get;set;}

public string WashingWay { get;set;}
}

class Fabric {
public ColoredDesign {  get;set;}

public float Length { get;set;}
}
```

there is a missing relationship between the design and color which specify the probable colors of single design.

The application is for a Fabric factory,

First they define the design and its colors, and define the way that each color in the specified design could be prepared in a property called washing way, and many other properties that is unique for each color in each design.

so each Fabric has to tell what color and design does it belong to.

for example: let's say I have the design named (A)
and it has the following colors:

- Red : ColoredDesignName : (A-RD), Washing way : W1
- Green : ColoredDesignName : (A-GN) Washing way : W2
- Blue : ColoredDesignName : (A-BL) Washing way : W3

and then I can have a Fabric which is of (A-RD) and has a length of 100M.

and another fabric of (A-BL) and 200 M Length.

Comment: did I miss anything ? is the question not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to answer your question because there is a missing part that is concerned by the business requirements that often drive the design. I'm doing DDD since several years and what helps me much when making a model is a business langage (translated to UL) and the requirments I should take into account.

I'm not sure you're concerned about the DDD but from your question I can say you're on the good tracks. For me the relationship between the Design and the Color could be effectively a ColoredDesign or ColouredDesign abstractions for example. Design and Color beeing just a part from which you're composing another abstraction that is important in you model. Thus your Fabric class is a very good thing you've introduced. It may contain a logic of creating a ColouredDesign objects, contains the constraints on how it should be constructed and so on. Then the client doesn't care about the creation logic and is not coupled to the creational constraints of the objects it consumes.

So from the few details I can read in your question I think is a viable design. Maybe others have another point of view on that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a property `public Color[] AvailableColors{get;set;}` in the `Design` class to express the availability of design in certain colors. Then in `Fabric` you may have two properties for Design and Color and check in business logic if the fabric color is one of the design available colors. I recommend that you remove the `ColoredDesign` class because IMO the real connection between Design and Color has no meaning without a Fabric. If for any reason you insist on having the `ColoredDesign` class, you should make the check on `ColoredDesign`'s  color instead of the `Fabric`'s as I mentioned before. If you keep `ColoredDesign` it will be as follows:

[image]

Comment: actually the relationship between the Design and Color has a meaning, and hold many attributes that wasn't mentioned, but may I didn't explain it well. I will edit the question to add more detail.

Comment: and I forgot to say that not only you have to specify the available colors but also you have to specify some more detail about the way that each color connected to a design (such the washing way, the machine that the combination can be installed on, the weight of each 1M of the combination ....etc

Comment: @Nour Does the washing way depend on the color only or the design too?What about the machine choice, does it depend on the color, design and the washing way ? also the same question about the weight per 1m, on what combination does it depend?

Comment: they all depend on both Color and Design. so the Red color can have a washing type for a design and another washing type for a different design, and the same is applied for the machine and weight.

Comment: @Nour If they all depend on Color and design then put them all in the ColoredDesign class but name it something more meaningful to reflect its new role.